# connect zookeeper client with ipv6 address

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ipv6

when i try to use ipv6 address to connect zookeeper, the zookeeper report next:
Error accepting new connection: /2409:8c10:c00:119:10:2:68:62 is a limited client, zk Server refused it!

i want to cennect zookeeper with ipv6 address